# Python: Logging into website with python using GET request

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

I'm using python 3.4.3 and I'm trying to login to OKCupid using requests.

The page that my code returns is the initial login page, not the page a user would see after successfully logging in. I have tried looking at several answers on here and other tutorials and most of them direct me to inspect the developer tab and look at requests with method "POST", but I do not see any such requests.

Instead, I see "GET" requests and I'm unsure how requests handle those. I have tried a number of different approaches, but none worked. Here is the simpler code I have:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

user='USERNAME'
pw='PASSWORD'
url='http://www.okcupid.com/login'

session=requests.session()

values = {'login_username':user, 'login_password':pw}
r = session.post(url,data=values)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
pSoup = BeautifulSoup.prettify(soup)

print(soup.title.string)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. In case this is helpful to someone in the future: there were two things preventing my previous code from working:

1. I needed to specify 'https' instead of 'http' in the url.
2. I was missing a the 'okc_api' value in the values vector. I hadn't detected this previously because Chrome's Developer tools did not have "Preserve log" checked. As a result, Chrome was erasing the login "POST" request before I could look at the "Form Data" Values.

Here is the revised code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

user='USERNAME'
pw='PASSWORD'
url='https://www.okcupid.com/login'

session=requests.session()

values = {'username': user, 'password': pw, 'okc_api': '1'}
session.post(url, data=values)
page = session.get('http://www.okcupid.com/')

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content)
print(soup.title.string)

session.close()
```